# SQL WHERE statement returning both or conditions

Tags: sql

I'm trying to return a single row based on this where statement

```
WHERE
    (C.id = G.community_id
     AND P.service_type_id = G.service_type_id 
     AND I.unit_class_id = G.unit_class_id)
    OR
    (C.id = G.community_id
     AND P.service_type_id = G.service_type_id)
```

The issue is I have to get a row based on multiple criteria and the more that match determines the final match. The statement above returns a row just fine if it matches the bottom or statement, but if it matches the first OR it returns results for both statements.

LIMIT 1 doesn't work either as sometimes it gives preference to the wrong result.

EDIT:

| community_id | service_type_id | unit_class_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | null |

Because of the way the table is both rows are true, my understanding was SQL took the first one that was true and returned it.

I apologize for not a lot of info I was hoping maybe there was just a bit of info I was missing. Here is my query.

```
CREATE VIEW view_invoice_line_item_gl_code 
AS
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT(ILI.invoice_line_item_id) AS invoice_line_item_id, 
        C.community_id AS community_id,
        S.service_type_id AS service_type_id,
        U.unit_class_id AS unit_class_id,
        LIP.line_item_provider_id AS line_item_provider_id,
        (SELECT gl_code_id
         FROM gl_code G  
         WHERE (C.community_id = G.community_id
                AND P.service_type_id = G.service_type_id)
           AND ((G.unit_class_id IS NULL 
                 AND G.line_item_provider_id IS NULL)
                OR
                (I.unit_class_id = G.unit_class_id
                 AND G.line_item_provider_id IS NULL)           
                OR
                (I.unit_class_id = G.unit_class_id
                 AND ILI.line_item_provider_id = G.line_item_provider_id)
               )) AS gl_code_id
    FROM 
        invoice I
    JOIN 
        invoice_line_item ILI ON (ILI.invoice_id = I.invoice_id)
    JOIN 
        invoice_header IH ON (I.invoice_header_id = IH.invoice_header_id)
    JOIN 
        provider_community_account PC  ON (I.provider_community_account_id = PC.provider_community_account_id)
    JOIN 
        line_item_provider LIP ON (ILI.line_item_provider_id = LIP.line_item_provider_id)
    JOIN 
        unit_class U ON (I.unit_class_id = U.unit_class_id)
    JOIN 
        community C ON (PC.community_id = C.community_id) 
    JOIN 
        provider P ON (PC.provider_id = P.provider_id)
    JOIN 
        service_type S ON (P.service_type_id = S.service_type_id)
```

Comment: (1) You need to provide sample data and desired results so it is clear what you are talking about.  (2) Tag with the database you are using.  (3) Explain why you have `join` conditions in the `where` clause.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Logically your conditions are: `IF (A AND B)  OR (A)` which is logically equivalent to just `IF A`.

Comment: What do you mean by "if it matches the first OR it returns results for both statements."?

Comment: Do you mean you want a record if it matches the first OR, but if there is NOT one then get one that matches the second?

Comment: It appears to be a logic issue. If something is true for the top condition it will always match the bottom condition.  You may want to add to the bottom condition AND I.unit_class_id <> G.unit_class_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm *assuming* that you want to get the record that matches the *most* conditions first.  One way to do that is to order by the number of matching conditions (in this case only one condition is different):

```
SELECT TOP 1 ...
FROM ...
WHERE
    C.id = G.community_id
    AND P.service_type_id = G.service_type_id 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN I.unit_class_id = G.unit_class_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
```

Comment: This is the closest, top 1 doesn't work with it, I'm guessing it's because it's a subselect? (sorry, you answered before I gave additional info so if that's the case it was my fault for not being clear enough)

Comment: I swapped TOP 1 for LIMIT 1 and it appears to be working just fine and I'm getting the result I need. Thanks!

Comment: So, I forgot I had a fourth column I need to match, it's one more step after unit_class_id, so if it and the rest don't match then it moves on to what you have above. Would you have an idea how I could add a fourth?

Comment: Sure - add another CASE and add its value to the first case (`CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`)

Answer (score 1):

The first condition implies the second, so you can simplify it like this:

```
WHERE
  C.id = G.community_id
  AND P.service_type_id = G.service_type_id
```

You say `where (A AND B) OR A` so `where A` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to compute a "score" somehow. If you consider each predicate awards 1 point, then you could do something like:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    case when <predicate1> then 1 else 0 end +
    case when <predicate2> then 1 else 0 end as score
  from t
  WHERE
    (C.id = G.community_id
    AND P.service_type_id = G.service_type_id 
    AND I.unit_class_id = G.unit_class_id
    )
  OR
    (
    C.id = G.community_id
    AND P.service_type_id = G.service_type_id
    )
)
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 1
```